# Responsive menu need to open below the bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

working on responsive menu section using below link for ref

[http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/index.html][1]

when I open this in 320x460 window resolution then menu opens above the Menu bar I want it below the bar

[image]

Comment: I never see that arrangement on that demo page. The large menu items and the menu button don't appear simultaneously.

Comment: Can you post the code or paste it in a Fiddle so we can mess with it and possibly provide you with a solution.

Comment: @isherwood you need to change the screen resolution if you are using firefox then check "Ctrl+Shift+M" you will get screens to change the resolution

Comment: @Leeish here is jsFiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/fzk3j/1/
you need to change screen resolution if you are using firefox then check "Ctrl+Shift+M"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fzk3j/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    <ul style="display: none;" class="clearfix">
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>

$('#pull').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Looks like you'll need to adjust your media queries to match. The menu doesn't appear at higher resolutions.

Edit: I see in your new fiddle that you're handling some of that with jQuery. Might be best left to CSS.

Comment: thanks isherwood it works for me as I wanted thanks for your quick reply